# How do I remove CSS code arriving in my webpage?

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I am trying to start using Chart.js on a webpage. This webpage resides on a server that is also running zabbix.

Here is the code for the simple page I am trying to run:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./Chart.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>ChartTest.php</h1>

        <canvas id="myChart" class="nogroup" width="400px" height="400px" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></canvas>

        <script>

         var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
         var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
             type: 'line',
             data: {
                 labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
                 datasets: [{
                     label: 'apples',
                     data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
                     backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                 }, {
                     label: 'oranges',
                     data: [2, 20, 22, 5, 2, 3, 10],
                     backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                 }]
             }
         });

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Fairly simple, right? I'm trying to make a chart on a 400 by 400 pixel canvas. But when I view the page in the browser, I see a huge chart that is larger than the viewable area of my screen. When I examine the code using chrome's inspect element feature, I see a lot of stylesheet information overwriting my canvas dimensions. It seems to be inheriting a class called "chartjs-render-monitor" from a class called "gr__zabbix_myservername_ext".

```
<canvas id="myChart" class="nogroup chartjs-render-monitor" width="1079" height="1079" style="width: 1079px; height: 1079px; display: block;"></canvas>
```

Simply by the name of the classes, I assume that this is related to zabbix. How can I find the css file that is causing this inheritance so I can add a "nogroup" class or something to override this behavior?  I cannot find where in the filesystem this css file is coming from... (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: I'd start by calling your chart something other than `myChart`. That's just asking for collisions. Keep in mind that even with the `var` keyword, that variable is on the global scope.

Comment: I don't follow your inheriting-a-class-from-a-class reasoning. CSS rules can only apply to one selector. Maybe post a snippet from the document inspector.

Comment: If a classname is present that you didn't define, it's being added by some javascript library.

Comment: You should put your canvas in a div and change the dimensions of the chart there and not in the canvas itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some research, I realized that the code causing this problem has nothing to do with Zabbix. It is actually a feature of Chart.js. Apparently, the library scales charts to fit the viewable width of the browser by default unless you set the "responsive" option to "false" when defining the chart. So, I changed the "myChart" variable definition to:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'apples',
         data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
         backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
      }, {
         label: 'oranges',
         data: [2, 20, 22, 5, 2, 3, 10],
         backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false
   }
});
```

It's that "responsive: false" in the options section that controls this behavior. So I was able to correct the issue that way. Thank you all for the comments and I'll try to rtfm next time!